# Git tags still in the file while solving conflicts in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, merge, egit, mergetool

the following situation is an example of what happens when i try to solve a conflict in Eclipse. I know i can use other ways to solve a conflict, i know how to solve conflicts, but i would like to use Eclipse and i apreciate if you could help. So, these are the steps:

(Using Eclipse 2019-09)
I'm in my branch:

1. Team > Merge > Select master
2. Eclipse tells there is conflict
3. Team Synchronize
4. (Now on Team Synchronizing view) Right Click on conflicting file > Merge Tool
5. I don't want to modify anything (even thou if i modify the problem occurs anyway)
6. Right Click on the file again > Add to index

After this, when i open the php perpective and open the file that was confliting these tags (<<>>refs) are there:

[image]

The weird thing is that Eclipse offers these 3 editors on the comparation view (after step 4). If i choose the Text Compare editor the tags doesn't remain in the code and everything works fine.

[image]

I know you may say "just switch to the text compare then" but it is annoying to do this everytime. So i'd like to know why this happens and if there is some way to solve it.

Comment: When you say that "the tags don't remain in the code", you mean that they trully aren't in the file (i.e. you don't see them when opening the file in another text editor like VS Code, Atom, etc.) or they are just not shown by the Text Compare editor? Because the conflicts markers (<<<>>>) are added by Git when a conflict occurs, so they should be present in the file anyway. IMHO the Text Compare editor just doesn't show them and outlines the difference by using double panes & colors instead

Comment: if i commit and push the tags go to the remote branch if i used the default editor, but if i use the text compare, they don't go to the remote, so, my guess is that they truly aren't in the file.

Comment: That the big diference, if i switch to the text compare, the hole process works fine. If i don't, i'll be pushing a file with that tags...

Comment: Those are not *tags* (which have a technical definition in Git). Those are *conflict markers*. Different conflict-resolution programs and tools use different ways to mark conflicts; pick a tool-set you like. (How to configure Eclipse is an Eclipse issue, not a Git issue.  I don't use Eclipse, but you tagged this with [git] so you got a Git comment.)